# Pentaho SQL Generator assigning UNKNOWN data type to table column

Tags: pentaho

**Pentaho Data Integration (CE) 5.0.1-stable** is trying to generate SQL with a column that has a data type as **UNKNOWN**

**example:**

```
, ad_unit_type VARCHAR(255)
, creation_time  UNKNOWN
, title VARCHAR(255)
```

- Original **Table Input** column is **DATETIME**
- There are no empty/null field values
- There are no transformations on field

Is there a way to force Pentaho to recognize the field as **DATETIME** in the transformation stream?

Best

Comment: What type of DB are you selecting from (Oracle, MS SQL, etc)?

Comment: Connecting from and to MySQL database

Answer (score 0):

- Insert **Select values** step
- Click to open/edit step
- Tab over to **Meta-data**
- Create new field with stream field name (ex: creation_time)
- Set **type** as **Date**
- Press **OK**

Can also directly define the data type in the **table input** step (using SQL's **CAST/CONVERT**).

Now, if you go to `Action > View SQL` you can see that the **UNKNOWN** data type has been replaced with **DATETIME**.